# (Python 3.7.0) (Windows 10) (Bash Terminal) Can't install dlib via pip3

Tags: python, cmake, visual-studio-code, pip, windows-10

Everytime I do pip3 install dlib, I receive errors such as "Failed with error code 1" and "CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt" and I have noticed that some work when I try to install other modules like numpy or pillow. And I am also using Visual Studio Code and bash for the terminal. I have tried to do it in the command prompt but it comes out with the same error.

Here is the full report:

```
David@Davids-PC MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Hello
$ pip3 install dlib
Collecting dlib
Using cached    https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/df/aa/6a9bb2a763107bb2606d6ee1aa65fcd3b51375a9ef6436e9c9280b0dd63c/dlib-19.15.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: dlib
Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
Complete output from command c:\users\david\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-56zr1ps9\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-zk0bruog\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_py
package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
running build_ext
Building extension for Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]
Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-56zr1ps9\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-56zr1ps9\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\david\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-56zr1ps9\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -A x64'
-- Building for: NMake Makefiles
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  Generator

    NMake Makefiles

  does not support platform specification, but platform

    x64

  was specified.


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/David/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-56zr1ps9/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-56zr1ps9\dlib\setup.py", line 257, in <module>
    'Topic :: Software Development',
  File "c:\users\david\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 131, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "c:\users\david\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "c:\users\david\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "c:\users\david\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\david\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "c:\users\david\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "c:\users\david\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\users\david\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\david\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "c:\users\david\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\users\david\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-56zr1ps9\dlib\setup.py", line 133, in run
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-56zr1ps9\dlib\setup.py", line 170, in build_extension
    subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
  File "c:\users\david\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 328, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-56zr1ps9\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-56zr1ps9\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\david\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-56zr1ps9\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\david\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-56zr1ps9\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-zk0bruog\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-56zr1ps9\dlib\
```

Comment: Have you compiled/installed dlib before installing its python API?

Comment: Oh, no. I have installed dlib and extracted the folder but I don't know how to compile it.

Comment: http://dlib.net/faq.html#HowcanIusedlibinVisualStudio

Comment: http://dlib.net/compile.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions but I installed it through a different way by using Anaconda with the command `Conda install dlib` in the Anaconda Prompt then created an environment for it. After that, I used Anaconda 5.3.0 in VSCode then started coding.